# Jquery accordion doesn't work in the IE7,8 versions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the latest jQuery UI - v1.10.2; the accordion functionality was not working as it should in IE 7, 8 versions,
    instead it works fine in all other browsers & even in IE 9..
    Calling the accordion with my div id `"accordion1"` as below:

```
$( "#accordion1" ).accordion();
```

This gives me an error `(SCRIPT87: Invalid argument)` in IE 7,8.
    Can anyone help me in solving this issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hmm....finally i got the answer..!
I've upgraded the jquery file to 1.8.3 version..that made to work perfectly in the IE 7 & 8 also
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Karthikr--> I didn't get what u r trying to say, what I've mentioned is that the thing that I've done to get the solution

Comment: this was auto generated. This answer needs a little more explanation. If it is a simple comment like "I upgraded to 1.8.3", it is better off being marked as a comment, as per StackOverflow standards.